# How do I break text onto a new line when it's not in a box?

Tags: svg

I have this html element. I'd like to break the text so Merced shows up on the next line.

```
<text transform="translate(374.14371673354304,603.9583614333004)" 
font-size="10   pt" fill="#787773" text-shadow="#000 0px 0px 0.5px"> 
Oceanview/Merced/Ingleside</text>
```

I tried to use a `\n` character and a `\r` character, without success.

Comment: `text` **is not an HTML element**.

Comment: what is it then?

Comment: An SVG element, you split them up with tspan elements to achieve line breaks.

Comment: well, it sure would be swell if someone helped answer the question

Comment: Is this in an `.html` file or `.svg` file?

Comment: it's in a .html file

Answer (score 0):

In not what you are trying to do but try this...

```html
<input type="text" transform="translate(374.14371673354304,603.9583614333004)" 
font-size="10   pt" fill="#787773" text-shadow="#000 0px 0px 0.5px" />
<p>Oceanview</p>
<p>Merced</p>
<p>Ingleside</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a SVG drawing, you can use `<br>` inside `<text>` to create line breaks:

```html
<svg width="100" height="100"><text y="50">Example<br>New Line</text></svg>
```

You can use CSS `line-height` and `margin` to control the paragraph size.